# C# WebMethod does not receive ClientDisconnectedToken on Azure

Tags: asp.net, web-services, azure, azure-web-app-service, asmx

I have a WebService.asmx with a long task running web method.
The duration is under the executionTimeout and the Azure limit of 230 seconds.
So, the request can await this 30 seconds operation and receive a response.

I want to stop the server operation, when the client disconnect.
So i read the httpContext.Response.ClientDisconnectedToken and passed that cancellationToken to my process.

I prepared a client that call this webMethod and set a timeout of 10 seconds, after that it will disconnect.

When i publish the webApplication on a on premise IIS, it works correctly and stops immediatly my server task when the client disconnect prematurely.

When i publish that on a App Service on Azure, it didn't recieve the client disconnection event.

Why the clientDisconnectedToken doesn't work?
I have a project available as demo and a published web service to test if needed.

Comment: `ClientDisconnectedToken` has a history of not working properly. It's possible that the ASP.NET version running your AppService is too old.

Comment: i have yet compared my locale IIS .Net Version with the Azure one, and they are the same. 4.6.xxx.

Comment: As mentioned in [HttpResponse.ClientDisconnectedToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.clientdisconnectedtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) :This property is only applicable to Internet Information Service (IIS) 7.5 in integrated mode. As I known, for Azure web app, the version is Microsoft-IIS/8.0. Have you checked this?

Comment: thank you for the support.

"This property is only applicable to Internet Information Service (IIS) 7.5 in integrated mode. If you invoke it without the right IIS version or pipeline mode, a PlatformNotSupportedException is thrown."

I yet checked the .Net version, the web server version and the pipeline. They are the same in my IIS on premise and Azure: IIS 8, Integrate.

I suppose that it throws an PlatformNotSupportedException if I am in wrong.

Comment: I created my WebService web project under .NET Framework 4.6.1, I could make it work as expected both on my side and Azure Web App. Have you tried to leverage [Remote debugging web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps) to put a breakpoint to see the details? Also, if possible please provide a demo and your published web service for test.